# When should fstrim run?

Tags: cyanogenmod, file-system, lagging, maintenance

Based on this [cyanogenmod forum thread](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/107760-freezing-apps-sluggish-behavior/), I tried to address the delay in running applications and switching between applications on my Galaxy Nexus running cyanogenmod with Android 4.4.4 by running fstrim manually.

```
root@maguro:/ # fstrim -v /data                                                          
/data: 11649122304 bytes trimmed                                                         
root@maguro:/ # fstrim -v /cache                                                         
/cache: 436121600 bytes trimmed                                                          
root@maguro:/ # fstrim -v /system                                                        
/system: 80490496 bytes trimmed
root@maguro:/ # exit
```

This has largely fixed the delay issues. The delay to return to the home screen, for example, has reduced from about 4 seconds to less than 1 second. Based on this performance boost, I expect the delay was caused by the filesystem running inefficiently.

Isn't the Android OS supposed to run fstrim on its own? When is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Does [this article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices) help you?  It discusses stock ROMs.  I don't know whether or not it applies to CyanogenMod.

Comment: @unforgettableid Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unforgettableid's comment included an [AnandTech article](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices) that describes the conditions under which fstrim is supposed to run:

> I’ve learned a bit more on the conditions underlying when Android 4.3 will TRIM filesystems, as it wasn’t completely clear before. The Android framework will send out a “start idle maintenance window” event that the MountService listens for, and then invokes vold to fstrim filesystems when a few conditions have been met – the device hasn’t been touched for over an hour, no idle maintenance window event has been sent in 24 hours, and the device is either off-charger with 80% battery or on-charger with 30% battery. The goal is to have fstrim run roughly once every 24 hours if you’re in the habit of plugging the device in to charge every night.

Answer (score 6):

The [article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/7185/android-43-update-brings-trim-to-all-nexus-devices) referenced in @[mattm](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/100457/mattm)'s answer is a bit outdated. `IdleMaintenanceService` was removed in Lollipop, things have changed. On Pie, scheduled `fstrim` is triggered from `StorageManagerService` <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#739))</sup> to `MountService` <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/MountServiceIdler.java#98))</sup>:

> if the device is alive at ***midnight + idle***, fstrim gets run at the next available ***charging + idle*** time

<sup>* ([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#535))</sup>
Mount service calls `StorageManager` which in turn calls `Vold` to do `fstrim`.

If the schedule is being missed because the conditions don't meet and `fstrim` has not run for last `3 days` <sup>([4](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#9213))</sup>, it will be forced during device startup if the device is restarted. `SystemServer` <sup>([5](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java#1027))</sup>, `PackageManager` <sup>([6](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#8929))</sup>, `StorageManager` <sup>([7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#953))</sup> and `Vold` <sup>([8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/VoldNativeService.cpp#470))</sup> are involved.

In each case, the file `/data/system/last-fstrim` <sup>([9](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#541))</sup> (since Lollipop) gets updated <sup>([10](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#581))</sup>, so  you can check its timestamp (**requires root**) to find out when `fstrim` was last run.

If you want to do `TRIM` manually, use Android's commandline tool **`sm fstrim` (requires root or `adb shell`**). Previously this was `vdc fstrim dotrim` but added to Storage Manager in Oreo <sup>([11](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/31d0b7043d9077ad8a0ebfbd6ff2f98621e6f413%5E%21/#F0))</sup> and removed from `vold` in Pie <sup>([12](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/11c2d380a786d9e304416be98881b90b74ff666d))</sup>.

In order to send `FITRIM ioctl` to selected filesystem(s) only, use `fstrim` tool (**requires root**); a busybox applet.

---

***What if you don't have root?***
And you suspect that the scheduled `fstrim` is being missed for 3+ days, restart device, `fstrim` will be forced (since Lollipop 5.1 <sup>([13](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-5.1.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#286))</sup>). Simple.

Apps can't TRIM without root; see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213987/218526).

---

**HOW OFTEN TRIM SHOULD BE RUN?**

Flash memory (including SSDs, eMMCs, SD Cards, USB sticks etc.) has limited number of Program/Erase cycles before it dies. But unlike HDDs, data can't be just overwritten on flash memory, it has to be Erased first, which is achieved through `Garbage Collection`.

Now if we do too much `fstrim`, this will cause frequent GC in background consuming precious `P/E` cycles and hence reducing life. If we don't do `fstrim` at all, there could be unnecessary GC (of already deleted data), plus the write operations will get too slow with time because `Erase` will have to be performed before overwriting data, which has very higher latency as compared to `Program` operation.

So we need a balance between both.

Also there are other factors e.g. whether eMMC controller supports `over provisioning`, how effective it is in background GC scheduling, wear-leveling and managing write amplification etc.

So unless you have the data sheet of your phone's eMMC and you are sure what you are doing, better is to leave the `fstrim` to OS. On PCs' <sup>([14](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fstrim.8.html))</sup>:

> Running fstrim frequently, or even using `mount -o discard`, might negatively affect the lifetime of poor-quality SSD devices.  For most desktop and server systems a sufficient trimming frequency is ***once a week***.

But this may vary with situations.

**RELATED:**

- [Coding for SSDs](http://codecapsule.com/2014/02/12/coding-for-ssds-part-3-pages-blocks-and-the-flash-translation-layer/)
- [Why is TRIM not supported on encrypted “/data” partition?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/214209/218526)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by mattm indicates conditions under which, `fstrim` should run. I am not aware if the behaviour has changed in subsequent Android versions, but I came across an app that does `fstrim` **on demand as also on reboot** . Root needed. Sharing this information as it may be useful to those who are not Linux savvy ( like me :)

**[SSD Boost](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.puandr.boost)**

> Android 4.3+ supports trim natively, it means that operating system after deleting a file will sends a trim command to nand controller notifying witch blocks the file used, the controller will erase them when idle so it can write fast without erasing next time.
>
> But users have no control over this process and Android doesn't trim the storage for a very long time.
>
> 'SSD Boost' helps you to run trim on your device manually if you feel it has become laggy and anyway it does trim for you on every reboot.

I know this directly doesn't answer the question, but felt this was the best question on site to share this

Comment: I did feel an improvement in terms of reducing lagging as claimed by the app but that could well be a placebo effect