# Androd device performance degradation with age

Tags: applications, hardware

How does the performance of an android device degrade ?

- Does not exiting the app age the device? Like not closing a browser tab but exiting internet app by swiping the app window from the one of the navigation Butt it because it is using ram?
- If too many apps start when powering on  bad for phone,does it cause it to slow time overtime or only the part when you power on.
- Over a time how does a device performance slow down,is it old hardware?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible, that old smartphone becomes slow simply because it is old?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/122804/is-it-possible-that-old-smartphone-becomes-slow-simply-because-it-is-old)

Comment: See [Why is my phone slow?] (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/why-is-my-phone-slow)

Comment: This site is best suited for single question and answer format. Multiple questions are discouraged