# Why is TRIM not supported on encrypted "/data" partition?

Tags: file-system, encryption, kernel, lagging, maintenance

I have a rooted `Lenovo A369i`. I use `LagFix (fstrim)` to TRIM partitions. Previously it was working well with `/data` but after I encrypted my phone it doesn't. I decrypted my phone by formatting. But now in the app it shows `/data` partition having kernel or hardware issues. It's not hardware because before encryption it was working well.

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone stumbles upon this, following conditions should be met for TRIM to work:

- Underlying hardware (eMMC) must support TRIM. For instance `Redmi Note 4` comes with MCP: [RX1BMB](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/mcp/KMRX1000BM-B614/) which contains `eMMC 5.1` and hence [supports TRIM](https://www.datalight.com/solutions/technologies/emmc/emmc-feature-comparison-by-version).
- Kernel must have support for TRIM, was added in [v3.1](https://asalor.blogspot.com/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html), but it is disabled by default and `vold` daemon must map `userdata` partition with `allow_discards` option, which it didn't in my case.

  If your `/data` partition is encrypted ([FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/)), ***Support for allow_discards was added in version 1.11.0*** ([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/cryptfs.cpp#1112)) of [device-mapper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_mapper) ***crypt*** <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/cryptfs.cpp#1047))</sup> target, but may not work e.g. on devices with Qualcomm SoCs. See [this issue](https://github.com/franciscofranco/mido/issues/6) for more details.
- Filesystem must also support TRIM <sup>([1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive#TRIM))</sup> (except if you want to TRIM a whole partition with `blkdiscard`). Android uses `ext4` or `f2fs` on `/data` partition, both support TRIM.

If these conditions meet, you can perform `TRIM` manually (`fstrim -v /data`) or periodically (scheduled service) or continuously (with `discard` mount option). See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213985/218526) for details on how often you should perform `fstrim`.