# This app promises to run "fstrim" without root but I am not sure if it works

Tags: root-access, file-system, lagging, maintenance

I am not sure if [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lagfix.fstrimmer) works. Can someone please help me? My phone is new and in its warranty period so I can't root it yet. I tried this app but I am not sure if it actually did something. Unlike the other famous app on the PlayStore for `fstrim`, it doesn't require root access which is quite incredible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, only apps running as root (UID 0) <sup>([1](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/PackageManagerService.java#8930))</sup> or system (UID 1000) <sup>([2](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/VoldNativeService.cpp#472))</sup> or with `android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS` <sup>([3](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r42/services/core/java/com/android/server/StorageManagerService.java#954))</sup> can do `fstrim`. But third party apps can neither get UID `0`/`1000` (without rooting phone), nor the said permission is for third party apps <sup>([4](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS))</sup>.

Also manually sending `FITRIM ioctl` with `fstrim` command requires at least capability `SYS_ADMIN` <sup>([5](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html))</sup>, which is almost root if not full root.

The app you have mentioned asks for permissions [CLEAR_APP_CACHE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#CLEAR_APP_CACHE) (delete all apps cache data) and [KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES) (close other apps). So it's quite evident what it must be doing to give a feel of lag-free experience.

**PS:** You don't need to run `fstrim` manually in most cases, OS can handle this. See [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213985/218526).

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it. I use an app called Trimmer which requires root to trim /cache, /data, /system. I installed this app & ran only selecting cache, but it shower trimeed cache & data. I ran a logcat, did not catch anything. So most probably it is a snake oil or at best it clears your cache.